# How to disable volume on Rhythmbox (Gstreamer) under Ubuntu

Tags: alsa, rhythmbox, volume-control

I'd like to use raspberry pi 3 + ubuntu for an "audiophile" sound. I have a m2tech Hiface Evo card that is connected to an external DAC.
I tried to use mpd + alsa with good results, but I would try to compare it with the Rhythmbox player using Gstreamer.
Now, the audiophile sound provides, among other things, the disabling of the volume. Hiface hasn't a hardware or software volume control.
In the mpd's config, however, I disabled the mixer with the value "none" and so I am sure I haven't the volume control (in various mpd's front-ends the volume bar is either disabled or has no effect on the sound).
I would like to achieve the same result with Rhythmbox and Gstreamer, but I can't find the right command on the web documentation. The Rhythmbox's volume control has effects on reproduction.
I precise that I have disabled Pulse and that I use alsa with Gstreamer.
How can I disable the volume on Gstreamer (or Rhythmbox) settings?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove, update and install the drivers for it.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If you also want to delete your local/config files for rhythmbox then this will work:

```
sudo apt-get purge rhythmbox
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get remove rhythmbox
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove rhythmbox
sudo apt-get install xxxx
```

While some may find it useful to have music players listed in the sound indicator menu with individual controls, installers of multiple software may want to blacklist some media players from appearing there. It can be done with this simple command, or edited in dconf Editor.

First, open the Terminal, then execute the following code:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound blacklisted-media-players "['rhythmbox']"
```

OR

Simply follow the instructions on this web page:

https://www.howtogeek.com/113897/how-to-remove-media-players-from-ubuntus-sound-menu-add-your-own/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try this evening... But there's one thing I'd like to understand... Rhythmbox uses Gstreamer. Is there a way to disable volume control in Gstreamer as in mpd in its mpd.conf (mixer=none or disable)?

Comment: No worries, welcome :) I think you could try this but revert back changes if you think something went wrong. There's 'replay_gain_handler' parameters are: <software, mixer or none>

According to 'mpd.conf' man page, It specifies how replay gain is applied. The default is "software", which uses an internal software volume control. "mixer" uses the configured (hardware) mixer control. "none" disables replay gain on this audio output.

Remember to reboot or logout/login for changes to take effect after running these commands. Let me know if you can make it work!

Comment: Manual for mpd.conf: 
https://linux.die.net/man/5/mpd.conf

Comment: The parameters that I use in mpd.conf for alsa are these: audio_output audio_output {
 type   "alsa"
 name   "My ALSA Device"
 device   "hw:0,0" # optional
        mixer_type   "none"
        mixer_device   "disabled"
        mixer_control   "PCM"}

Comment: Is there something similar for Gstreamer?

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work. I tried to include Rhythmbox in the blacklist, but the player's volume control is always on and the volume is affected by it. In other word I would bypass/disable the Rhythmbox volume control.